No match was found for the specified search criteria and module name 'MicrosoftPowerBIMgmt.Profile'

Not able to install any MicrosoftPowerBIMgmt packages in azure release pipeline.
No match was found for the specified search criteria and module name 'MicrosoftPowerBIMgmt.Profile'. Try Get-PSRepository to see all available registered module repositories.
Tried checking actual packages in powershell gallery website but got below error


Same issue on my end, only for MicrosoftPowerBIMgmt.Profile, the other modules are okay. Suggest you install the rollup module MicrosoftPowerBIMgmt which contains all the modules.

I checked. Even it did not work for me. Seems like a genuine issue. You can raise a case with MS to resolve this. Thanks for pointing this out

Here is a ticket with the same issue from module developer site: https://github.com/microsoft/powerbi-powershell/issues/408 It seems that many users have the same issue now.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I can reproduce the same issue a few minutes ago. But now it seems that the issue has gone.
We can access the PowerShell module site: MicrosoftPowerBIMgmt.Profile  successfully.

And we can install the MicrosoftPowerBIMgmt.Profile module successfully with the command:
 Install-Module MicrosoftPowerBIMgmt.Profile -Scope CurrentUser -Force


Thanks! Microsoft seems to have fixed it.

Glad to know that it can work fine now.
